# How do I get my dwarfs to kill a Giant Rat?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a Giant Rat running around in my fortress eating my stores and drinking my drinks (kind of like a new peasant, actually). How do I get my dwarfs to drop what they are doing and just massacre the thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have some dwarves assigned to a [squad](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Squad) already you just need to issue a kill order to the squad.  First open the squad menu with <kbd>s</kbd>, select your squad by pressing the letter next to it.  On the squad menu, press <kbd>k</kbd> to issue a `kill` order, then <kbd>l</kbd> to list enemies, move to the rat, and press enter. The squad will automatically move to the rat and attack it.

Comment: It is complicated... I am still thinking about (or betting enough bravery to) starting to learn DF, and responses like this intimidate me. How often do rats like this appear during the course of a game? When they do, though, I think your answer will be a lifesavier to me, as I will surely not remember so many keys!

PS Rat, not bat. Still your answer is useful :)

Comment: @NPC It sounds more complicated than it is.  You don't have to memorize `s`,`k`,`l`, you can muddle your way through the screens (which I usually do).  There's a helpful menu tab (that you can hide) that shows all the menu keys.  The hardest part is figuring out where to use `-` and `+` vs `down` and `up` in a menu.

Comment: The kill command also has direct targeting, so if you can see the rat you can just designate it with the cursor.