# My dwarf is in a strange mood. How can I fix him?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A certain dwarf has been taken by a strange mood due to a lack of chairs and clean water.  I designated a new water-hole for them and built him seven chairs, but he is still depressed.

How do I make him happy again or is there I way I can prevent him from sitting on the chairs, drinking clean water, eating hard earned food, and not doing any work? (ie try him and have him executed/banished?)

EDIT:

The situation has worsened.  He has gone stark raving mad!

Comment: quick set up a prison.

Comment: If he's gone stark raving mad, I think it's too late for him, unfortunately.

Comment: Must.  Kill.  Crazy.  Dwarf.

Comment: The strange mood is not caused by a lack of chairs or water, by the way - these things happen (more or less) randomly, although with a certain regularity.

Comment: and if they end successfully, the can be a blessing for your fortress.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Minor Spoilers!

---

If the dwarf has a *strange mood* he has probably taken a workshop which if you query will list the objects or hints to objects which he needs to fulfill his mood.  If he fulfills his mood good things will happen.  If not, some form of **FUN** will ensue.

You can try to execute him, with magma, spikes, or some other devious trap.  You cannot order another dwarf to kill him though.

---

**IF** the dwarf goes stark raving mad, you may [kill him as if he was an enemy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-do-i-get-my-dwarfs-to-kill-a-giant-rat/3485#3485).

Comment: once he goes mad you can kill him, possibly during the strange mood.

Comment: The best way to avoid this happening is to make him his workshop and make sure you can close the door. If he goes mad you can then just forbid the door and wait for him to starve.

Comment: I always wall in dwarves as soon as it becomes clear they can't possibly get their required materials. I don't trust forbidden doors :)

Comment: I setup war dogs and put my militia on alert.  At least they should get experience from putting down the lunatic.

Comment: @ArdaXi I feel strangely depressed after locking Datan in the workshop and watching him die of thirst.  I'm not even joking... I think I need some unicorns now.

Comment: @Mechko, Just remember, [Unicorns](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Unicorn) can be a source of [Fun](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Fun)

Answer (score 4):

Avoiding spoilers, have you considered what he likes doing for a craft? Does he have the ability (workshop, raw materials) to do that?

Comment: Is it sufficient to simply 'make' him like something?

Comment: No--he's got a mind of his own right now.