# A dwarf is possessed, how can I find what he wants?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

There is a dwarf that "has been possessed" and now he's in the meeting hall waiting for something. I'm guessing I don't have the workshop he needs but how can I found out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My dwarf is in a strange mood. How can I fix him?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5127/my-dwarf-is-in-a-strange-mood-how-can-i-fix-him)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check his skills.

He's likely to want a workshop related to one of the skills he already has.

Note that precursor making skills like weaving and mining relate to the workshop to which the production skill is related; a weaver will want a Clothiers Workshop; a miner will want a Masons Workshop; and a tanner, if they mood at all, will want leather works.

[From Magmawiki:](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Strange_mood)

[image]

Comment: Note that he's most likely looking for the workshop associated with his /highest/ skill. Of course, if that turns out to be glassblowing and you're on a non-sandy-area map, you have a problem...

Comment: @Shadur: Nope; not as long as you've picked a few pieces of glass off of the merchants; moody glass makers don't use sand, they use raw glass.

Comment: The merchant has just gone and I bought only "big guns" for my army. Yep, I'm a sociopath. Tnx for the advice, I'll look into his skills.

Comment: Ok, it's a glass maker and he needs green glass but I have red sand.I even need a bag. I just builded walls around the workshop for now.

Comment: @dierre: All kinds of sand give the same kind of glass. Red sand will make green glass, as will yellow, white and black. After all, there's no green sand, is there?

Comment: Doesn't matter, he was killed :P I tried to make bags but every bag was used to store seeds and in the meanwhile he went berserk, my legendary mason was closed inside the wall with him and you know...the story ended tragically for the glassmaker...